# how can i Read the countries_data.json data file in data directory, and create a function that finds the ten most spoken languages using python

Tags: python

https://github.com/Asabeneh/30-Days-Of-Python/blob/ff24ab221faaec455b664ad5bbdc6e0de76c3caf/data/countries_data.json

how can i Read the `countries_data.json`(link above) data file in data directory, and create a function that finds the ten most spoken languages

i have no ideal on how to go about this

```
# output should look like this:
print(most_populated_countries(filename='./data/countries_data.json', 10))

[
{'country': 'China', 'population': 1377422166},
{'country': 'India', 'population': 1295210000},
{'country': 'United States of America', 'population': 323947000},
{'country': 'Indonesia', 'population': 258705000},
{'country': 'Brazil', 'population': 206135893},
{'country': 'Pakistan', 'population': 194125062},
{'country': 'Nigeria', 'population': 186988000},
{'country': 'Bangladesh', 'population': 161006790},
{'country': 'Russian Federation', 'population': 146599183},
{'country': 'Japan', 'population': 126960000}
]`
```

Comment: You are simply asking people to do your assignment for you

Answer (score 0):

You can load your json file using `json` and `requests`. After that you can use the `sorted` function of python using a user defined `key`.

```
import json
import requests

def get_data(url:str='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Asabeneh/30-Days-Of-Python/ff24ab221faaec455b664ad5bbdc6e0de76c3caf/data/countries_data.json'):
    res = requests.get(url)
    if res.status_code == 200:
        return res.content.decode()

def get_json():
    data = get_data()
    return json.loads(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    js = get_json()
    s = sorted(js, key=lambda x: x.get('population', 0), reverse=True)
    print(*[d['name'] for d in s[:5]], sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
China
India
United States of America
Indonesia
Brazil
```